# Using Task.Run for IO bound work to avoid updating method signatures

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-4.7.2

This method contains a bunch of Redis code, and is called in many places and is part of a deep method call stack:

```
public void Save()
{            
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var transaction = cache.CreateTransaction();
        var _ = transaction.StringSetAsync();
        _ = transaction.SetAddAsync();      
        await transaction.ExecuteAsync();
    }).Wait();
}
```

I understand a thread pool thread will be used to do this work, and that the calling thread will be blocked via the `Wait()` call, and will be unable to take any more ASP.NET requests as it waits for the Redis code to finish.

Would this blocking be insignificant enough to warrant keeping the code how it is to avoid having to update the signature of all the methods that call this code to include `async`/`await`?

Also, because only `transaction.ExecuteAsync()` is `await`ed in the delegate, could `transaction.ExecuteAsync()` be run before the `Task`s above it had completed?

Comment: Make `Save` asynchronous instead. The overhead is *significant*, 2 blocked threads. Each HTTP request is already served by a different threadpool thread. This `Task.Run().Wait()` blocks the current threadpool thread only to start another that does nothing but wait for IO to complete. You end up with *two* blocked threads. If `Save` itself was async no thread would be blocked. The request thread would be released to serve other requests while waiting

Comment: BTW why are `StringSetAsync` etc ignored? This will result in a race condition at the very least and possibly even lost updates. `ExecuteAsync` can easily complete before the previous calls

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What sort of negative effects could we expect from this? It's only called when a user logs in. We have thousands of users, who all probably log in between 8am and 10am week days. We haven't noticed any issues yet. Could it be that the Azure load balancer is working well enough to hide any negative effects?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos why two threads are blocked? - blocked is that one, which calls`Wait()`. The problem is that, 2 threads are used for executing one set of instructions instead of one.

Comment: Did you check your Azure bill? It may be triple what it should. If it wasn't for Azure's automatic scaling you could encounter cascading server meltdowns too. Blocking starts with spinwaiting because blocks are supposed to be *short*-lived and thread-switching is expensive. This means you're pegging cores at 100% doing nothing. If you have high enough traffic, more and more servers may end up doing nothing, moving traffic to the *other* ones. At some point IIS may start recycling app pools that are at 100% for too long

Comment: `why two threads are blocked` the code is blocking both the request thread *and* the thread used to execute `Task.Run`. Had you used `async/await` no thread would be blocked

Comment: @Ryan and if you think the cascading meltdown is an exaggeration, ask me how we found out about this on an installation with 1M heavy requests per day. It took several meltdowns and an irate CEO to persuade lead developers to stop blocking though

Comment: Look at this another way - why use such overcomplicated code when you can just call your Redis code directly? What are the *benefits* of this that make it worth two blocked threads per request?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, why that one thread inside `Task.Run` is blocked? Redis-client implementation?

Comment: @Ryan the thread running the delegate code inside Task.Run is blocked because it's calling Redis methods which are asynchronous, ie. IO bound, not CPU bound (at least that is what I believe if we assume the Redis developers didn't implement fake async methods).

Comment: @DavidKlempfner, NO, this is misconception, tasks were designed for those specific IO-operations, it's their primary goal. `await` calls are never blocking, (there are some exceptions - Sqlite provider implementation).

Comment: @DavidKlempfner as a final thought, just rewrite Save to be async (with awaits). With IO-calls inside, `Save` method would release calling thread quite fast.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think @Ryan has a good point. Because the delegate contains `await transaction.ExecuteAsync()`, doesn't that mean the thread that was running the delegate code is free to take on other requests while `transaction.ExecuteAsync()` is running?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner the whole idea behind async/await, in a nutshell, is to use CPUs resources till it makes sense. If there is some IO (main use case), thread is free to go, no need to be busy-waiting.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner not really. I should have said 2 threads wasted and 1 blocked. I haven't noticed the `async` but that just means the 2nd thread is wasted trying to *start* an asynchronous operation that yields. If you have thousands of concurrent requests that means thousands of wasted threads

Comment: @Ryan that `.Wait()` still blocks. `async/await` was built to remove that `.Wait()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Isn't it one thread wasted/blocked? The calling thread is blocked and therefore wasted because it can't do anything except wait. However, the thread running the delegate code kicks off some Tasks, and is then free to take on other requests while `transaction.ExecuteAsync()` is running?

Comment: And another thread was wasted to start the lambda. What's the point of this discussion? You asked if the code is wasteful compared to the normal code, yes it is and I've seen the consequences. The cost of refactoring may not be as high of the risk/cost of the code in your scenario, but that's out of scope for SO questions or even codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: In fact, the exact question `Would this blocking be insignificant enough to warrant keeping the code` can't be answered because it depends entirely on your project's specific circumstances. It could easily be closed as `opinion-based`.

Comment: "And another thread was wasted to start the lambda" - You can't avoid a thread running the redis code. Either it happens on the main thread or it happens in a thread pool thread. So I don't think you can say two threads wasted and one blocked. It's one thread blocked only. You made a claim that two threads were wasted, Ryan was saying this wasn't true. The point of this discussion was to clarify which is correct. It was a good learning experience for me, regardless of whether or not it had to do with the exact question I asked.

Comment: Your first question is pretty opinion-based. I would say change it to async, but how many is "many places"? My primary concern re blocking on ASP.NET is thread pool exhaustion; a *lot* of framework-level I/O assumes an available thread pool.

Comment: @StephenCleary what about the 2nd question? Do you think there could be a race condition because `StringSetAsync()` and `SetAddAsync()` aren't `await`ed?

Comment: Yes. Others already answered that part.

Comment: @StephenCleary according to Marc Gravell, you should not use await:
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/711#issuecomment-1767769216

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a very strange API decision.